# Thunderbird plug-in to search all folders

Tags: gratis, thunderbird, plug-in

I may have misunderstood how Thunderbird works, but when I press `ctrl + shift + F`, I must specify an account and a folder within it.

I want to be able to search all mail. Is there a plug in to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No plugin necessary, Thunderbird comes with a global search built in.

The default shortcut for that is `Ctrl - K` (but I couldn't find the menu item to be honest).

You can put a "Global Search" input field into the toolbar.

See the Thunderbird help for details: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/global-search

Comment: Lolx!  I have been using Ctrl+Shidt+F and had totally forgotten Ctrl+k  A pity I can't search from/to/title. etc using that, not search with/out attachemnts or by date